# hugo URLs with protocol (http) not supported

Tags: hugo, docsy

I am using hugo (https://gohugo.io/) and trying to make an external link in the menu (docsy theme).

I changed the _index.md to:

```
---
title: "Documentation"
linkTitle: "Documentation"
url: "https://www.myurl.com"
weight: 20
menu:
  main:
    weight: 20
---
```

However hugo reports:

```
Rebuild failed: URLs with protocol (http*) not supported
```

Could anyone advise of how to create an external URL link directly on the menu?

Thanks, Gregor

Comment: https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#set-url-in-front-matter

Comment: Actually found the answer for the hugo docsy theme here: https://www.docsy.dev/docs/adding-content/navigation/

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you post the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that "url" is a predefined [front matter variable](https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#front-matter-variables) that is meant to be used for defining the full path to the content page from the site root. If you want to add an external link in your front matter, I'd recommend giving the variable a different name, e.g. "external_url".

Answer (score 0):

I just added something like this:

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "GitHub"
    weight = 50
    url = "https://github.com/google/docsy/"
```

To the config.toml file.

I found this solution for the docsy theme here: https://www.docsy.dev/docs/adding-content/navigation/

Hope this helps, Gregor